# SQL: Querying 2 tables and sort results by values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to select all the comments for a single record and order them by the overall ratio of positive:negative votes from another table?

I think I may need to use a subselect but I really am not sure how or where.

2 tables:

table 1 [Comments]

```
ID  |  RecordID  |  Comment  
------------------------------
1   | 100001     | blah blah
2   | 100202     | another co
3   | 100054     | lorem ips
```

table 2 [Ratings]

```
ID  | CommentID  |  Vote  
-------------------------
1   | 1          | 1       
2   | 1          | 0
3   | 1          | 1
4   | 3          | 0
5   | 3          | 0
6   | 3          | 0
```

Please note: 'Vote' : 0 = negative vote; 1 = positive vote
Also, I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: can you provide desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort them from positive to negative rating you can do:

```
SELECT c.id,
  c.recordID,
  c.comment
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CommentID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) AS RATING FROM ratings
  GROUP BY commentID
  ) r ON r.commentID = c.id
ORDER BY r.RATING DESC;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddda7/9)</kbd>

Note that i am using the CASE to give votes with 0 a value of -1, otherwise, 10 negatives and one positive would give a rating of 1.

This query is not taking into account the comments without scores. If you want to have the comments without scores to have 0 rating, you could do:

```
SELECT c.id,
  c.recordID,
  c.comment
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT CommentID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) AS RATING FROM ratings
  GROUP BY commentID
  ) r ON r.commentID = c.id
ORDER BY COALESCE(r.RATING,0) DESC;
```

EDIT:

To get the ratio try this:

```
SELECT c.id,
  c.recordID,
  c.comment,
  r.rating
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT CommentID,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN Vote = 1
          THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) / (nullif(COUNT(*) * 1.0, 0)) AS RATING
  FROM ratings
  GROUP BY commentID
  ) r ON r.commentID = c.id
ORDER BY COALESCE(r.RATING, 0) DESC;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddda7/29)</kbd>

Comment: Since you use an INNER JOIN, all comments without votes would not be included in the Result. This is probably not intended.

Comment: @Twinkles. True. i will add some reference to that.

Comment: Thankyou this is very useful. However, is it expressed as a ratio? As I understand, it is just VotesUp - VotesDown, giving a non-decimal result like '23' or whatever. Is there a way to make it a ratio, e.g. if there were 2 +votes and 0 -votes then it would be 1.00. Or if there were 2 +votes and 1 -vote it would be 0.5 etc. Thanks

Comment: @Kelsey You will have to elaborate: What will be the ratio for zero plus and 2 negative, what will be the ratio for a comment without votes? Best would be you provide a mathematical formula.

Comment: I was thinking something like this (I did not write this!)
`convert(decimal(5,2),(convert(float,VotesUp)/convert(float,VotesDown))) as Rating`

Comment: Any comment without upvote would yield zero, any comment without downvote would be "Division by zero". This does not work.

Comment: Is there another way Twinkles?